# Why do I get an error about the initializer not being a constant?

Tags: c, constants, initializer

I am using the following code.

```
const int X_ORIGIN = 1233086;             
const int Y_ORIGIN = -4728071;              
const int Z_ORIGIN = 4085704;
const int xyzOrigin[NUM_DIMENSIONS] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN};
```

When I compile it, GCC gives me the following error.

> Transformations.h:16:1: error: initializer element is not constant

What does that mean? How can I fix my code?

Comment: Why not create a struct which contains the three positions, rather than an array? Seems a bit counter-intuitive...

Comment: corollary to what @nathanwhite said, John Carmack said: https://twitter.com/ID_AA_Carmack/status/219884864185446402

Comment: Related: *[Variably modified array at file scope in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13645936/variably-modified-array-at-file-scope-in-c)*.

Comment: `NUM_DIMENSIONS` isn't defined anywhere, and there's no line 16 in this program.  It's just not reproducible.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't do this at global scope in C, only at local scope, i.e. within a function:

```
#define NUM_DIMENSIONS 3

const int X_ORIGIN = 1233086;             
const int Y_ORIGIN = -4728071;              
const int Z_ORIGIN = 4085704;

const int xyzOrigin[NUM_DIMENSIONS] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN}; // FAIL

void foo(void)
{
    const int xyzOrigin[NUM_DIMENSIONS] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN}; // OK
}
```

Alternatively you could compile the code as C++ rather than C.

Comment: That define rather than const int is important. Darn size cannot be any type of variable (even a constant) apparently.

Comment: Only for automatic storage class which means within a function **and not static (or C11 _Thread_local)**.

Answer (score 21):

Often people are mislead by the naming of the keyword `const`, implying something of a constant value that can't be changed. In C at least, it means **readonly**. `const` qualified objects at file scope are not having the proper constness to serve as array initializers.

As an example for non-constant constness, it is perfectly ok to declare

```
 const volatile unsigned int milliseconds_since_boot;
```

being a value that gets updated from outside the compiler's control (think HW register) and that you are not allowed to assign to, i.e. it is readonly.

Comment: Not my DV, but you could elaborate a bit cloaser on OPs actual problem. The example is hard to comprehend for beginners who might not even know what a "HW register" is.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a proper programmer ;) but I'd do this:

```
#define X_ORIGIN (1233086)
#define Y_ORIGIN (-4728071)
#define Z_ORIGIN (4085704)
const int xyzOrigin[NUM_DIMENSIONS] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN};
```

That way it's just a text-substitution. If the compiler still spits the dummy at least you're a step closer to knowing where the issue is.

Comment: @nathanwhite Care to elaborate? The macros solve the problem just fine! (Assuming `NUM_DIMENSIONS` is defined somewhere).

Comment: @nathanwhite Those are precisely the causes for the "initializer element is not constant" error(s). Having `NUM_DIMENSIONS` as a variable (const qualified or not), causes a "variably modified »xyzOrigin« at file scope".

Comment: Better still would be to remove `NUM_DIMENSIONS` altogether and let the array size itself to the number of elements provided.

Answer (score 4):

As an alternative, this would also work in this case:

```
enum { X_ORIGIN = 1233086,
       Y_ORIGIN = -4728071,
       Z_ORIGIN = 4085704 };

const int xyzOrigin[] = { X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN };

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

*In C language objects with static storage duration has to be initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions. --[Answer of AndreyT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025106/1530410)*

After reading, You must have the knowledge that `NUM_DIMENSIONS`, If it has the `const`-qualification, isn't a constant! Then you can't initializate your array this way.

For use this code:

`const int xyzOrigin[NUM_DIMENSIONS] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN};`

You should use: `#define NUM_DIMENSIONS 3` or you could just declare without any variable inside the square brackets `const int xyzOrigin[] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN};`

Answer (score 0):

As triclosan said:

```
main()
{
    const int X_ORIGIN = 1233086;
    const int Y_ORIGIN = -4728071;
    const int Z_ORIGIN = 4085704;
    const int xyzOrigin[] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN};
}
```

this works fine...

or, if you know the dimensions beforehand, this:

```
#define DIM 3

main()
{
    const int X_ORIGIN = 1233086;
    const int Y_ORIGIN = -4728071;
    const int Z_ORIGIN = 4085704;
    const int xyzOrigin[DIM] = {X_ORIGIN, Y_ORIGIN, Z_ORIGIN};
}
```