# initializer element is not constant - how to solve the errors?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

following this [link](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~baker/devices/lxr/http/source/linux/samples/kobject/kobject-example.c)

I did:

```
static const struct attribute const *attrs1= {
        &foo_attribute.attr,
        NULL,
};
 static const struct attribute_group const attr_group = {
       .attrs = attrs1,
};
```

but get these errors:

```
error: initializer element is not constant
error: (near initialization for 'attr_group.attrs')
```

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w) solution but didn't understand how to solve it...

**EDIT:**
the line triggered the error:

```
.attrs = attrs1,
```

Comment: what line triggers the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, another `struct` object or the contents of another variable will never be considered a constant expression that could be used in an initializer for a `static` object.

But your first initialization also is bogus. Probably you meant

```
static const struct attribute * const attrs1= &foo_attribute.attr;
```

So your initialization of the second would read something like

```
static const struct attribute_group attr_group = {
       .attrs = &foo_attribute.attr,
};
```