# Replacing deprecated "dev_attrs" attribute with "dev_groups"

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I'm trying to compile a Linux device driver (kernel module), however the module was last updated in April 2013 and of course it doesn't compile anymore on a recent (3.13) kernel, here's the error :

```
als_sys.c:99:2: error: unknown field ‘dev_attrs’ specified in initializer
```

I've searched already but all that I found were patches, there is no clear "tutorial" about updating an old module, the only thing I understood was that I need to use `dev_groups` instead, but it doesn't accept the same value as `dev_attrs` and I don't know how to adapt the existing code for that.

The code (some of it, the entire code can be found [here](https://github.com/seidler2547/linux-acpi-als/tree/master/drivers)) :

```
# als_sys.c

static ssize_t
illuminance_show(struct device *dev, struct device_attribute *attr, char *buf)
{
    struct als_device *als = to_als_device(dev);
    int illuminance;
    int result;

    result = als->ops->get_illuminance(als, &illuminance);
    if (result)
        return result;

    if (!illuminance)
        return sprintf(buf, "0\n");
    else if (illuminance == -1)
        return sprintf(buf, "-1\n");
    else if (illuminance < -1)
        return -ERANGE;
    else
        return sprintf(buf, "%d\n", illuminance);
}

# truncated - also "adjustment_show" is similar to this function so
# I didn't copy/paste it to save some space in the question

static struct device_attribute als_attrs[] = { # that's what I need to modify, but
    __ATTR(illuminance, 0444, illuminance_show, NULL), # I have no clue what to
    __ATTR(display_adjustment, 0444, adjustment_show, NULL), # put here instead
    __ATTR_NULL,
};

# truncated

static struct class als_class = {
    .name = "als",
    .dev_release = als_release,
    .dev_attrs = als_attrs, # line 99, that's where it fails
};
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the answer below, I changed the code like this :

```
static struct device_attribute als_attrs[] = {
    __ATTR(illuminance, 0444, illuminance_show, NULL),
    __ATTR(display_adjustment, 0444, adjustment_show, NULL),
    __ATTR_NULL,
};

static const struct attribute_group als_attr_group = {
    .attrs = als_attrs,
};

static struct class als_class = {
    .name = "als",
    .dev_release = als_release,
    .dev_groups = als_attr_group, # line 103 - it fails here again
};
```

But I still get another error :

`als_sys.c:103:2: error: initializer element is not constant`

I've found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130846/initializer-element-is-not-constant-how-to-solve-the-errors) which is about the same error however its answer is about a single attribute and I don't know how to adapt it for multiple ones.

Thanks for your help and have a nice day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Indeed, `dev_attrs` was replaced with `dev_groups` in 3.13. In 3.12 they were both presented in struct. Look at [3.12 version](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/device.h?v=3.12#L356) and [3.13 version](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/device.h#L351).

Anyway, there should not be a problem, because simple [search for `attribute_group`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=attribute_group) gives you a lot of examples.

Simply put, you have to embed your dev_attrs inside dev_group:

```
static const struct attribute_group als_attr_group = {
        .attrs = als_attrs,
};
```

And then use that attribute group in struct class.

There is also a handy macro `ATTRIBUTE_GROUPS`. See example usage https://lkml.org/lkml/2013/10/23/218.

**EDIT**:

Remove `const` declaration from attribute group like this:

```
static struct attribute_group als_attr_group = {
        .attrs = als_attrs,
};
```

Because you can't initialize const struct with something that is not literal like `0xff` or `'c'`. See more detailes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w).

Comment: Thanks but your solution gives me another error, please look at my edited question.

Comment: Actually, `const` or not makes no difference, exact same error at the exact same line.

Comment: Well, I can keep guessing what thing you should tinker to avoid compilation error, but it starts to be off-topic regarding to your original question.

Comment: Ok thanks anyway, I'll post that as a separate question.