# Variable being used without being initialized c++

Tags: c++

I'm relatively new to C++.
I'm using a function to give an object some values, but I keep getting the error that the object is being used without being initialized. How come?

The definition of `Worker`:

```
class Worker 
    public:
    int telephone;
    char firstname[20];
    char task[100];
    int salary;
    int id;
};
```

The actual code:

```
Worker worker1;
worker1 = getWorker(worker1);

Worker getWorker(Worker worker){
    cout << "First name: ";
    cin >> worker.firstname;
    return worker;
```

Comment: "I've done basically the same in Java" Yes, and as you may have noticed, they are not the same languages.

Comment: What's the exact diagnostic message? How is `Worker` defined?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [initializing static variable with a function call gives compilation error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720400/initializing-static-variable-with-a-function-call-gives-compilation-error)

Comment: Which line raises the error?

Comment: Just avoid these kind of sentences. I'll not be the only one making fun of it.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus worker1 = getWorker(worker1);

Comment: Have you tried talking in France in English - That does not work either (well sometimes)

Comment: @EdHeal Have you ever been original?

Comment: name of `get_worker` is misleading. And it's design seems flawed.

Comment: Just curious as to why you think that two languages (programming or otherwise) would work the same

Comment: @EdHeal Just forget it. Do you know why I'm getting the error?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Is that related to the error?

Comment: @Jullix993: It is somewhat related -- you wouldn't get the error, if you didn't take `worker` as parameter.

Comment: @Jullix993: what is `getWorker` supposed to do?

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus Yes I just noticed that, I don't understand that. I declared a Worker in the function instead of getting one in the parameter, and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getWorker` doesn't need an argument. Use a local object to get the input, and return it:

```
Worker getWorker() {
    Worker worker;
    // whatever
    return worker;
}
```

Also, use **initialization** instead of creating objects then assigning to them. Like this:

```
Worker worker1 = getWorker();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you haven't explicitly set the value of firstname there could be any kind of garbage stored in the 20 bytes that make up firstname. char buffers are 0 terminated, so best practice would be to give an initial value to firstname in a default constructor:

```
Worker(){
  //omitting other code
  firstname[0] = '\0';
}
```

Of course, if you want the variable to hold an actual value it would be best to pass it into the constructor.