# warning: initializer element is not constant

Tags: c

all,

I have below C code, when I compiling,

```
static struct 
{
    const char* val;
    const char* parse_key;
    int len;  //parse key length
    void (*parse_routine) (const char* after, rtsp_sdp_t* response);
} sdp_header[] =
{
#define SDP_FILL_STRUCT(a,b) {#a, b, strlen(b), sdp_##a}
    SDP_FILL_STRUCT(attr_control, "a=control:"),    
    SDP_FILL_STRUCT(attr_framerate,"a=framerate:"),
    SDP_FILL_STRUCT(attr_range, "a=range:"),    
    {'\0', '\0', 0, (void*)0},  

};
```

why it gives out bellow errors:

```
:330: warning: initializer element is not constant
:330: warning: (near initialization for 'sdp_header[0]')
:331: warning: initializer element is not constant
:331: warning: (near initialization for 'sdp_header[1]')
:332: warning: initializer element is not constant
:332: warning: (near initialization for 'sdp_header[2]')
:333: warning: initializer element is not constant
```

I don't know exactly what's the reason, could you please give me some help. thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C89/90 all brace-enclosed initializers were required to be constants. In C99 and later brace-enclosed initializers for objects *with static storage duration* must be constants.

This is what you have in your case: `sdp_header` is an array with static storage duration, which means that you are only allowed to use constants between the `{}`.

It appears that all of your initializers are constants besides the `strlen` ones. Function call does not produce a constant. In your specific case you can replace `strlen` with `sizeof`

```
#define SDP_FILL_STRUCT(a,b) {#a, b, sizeof b - 1, sdp_##a}
```

but it will work only if `b` stands for a literal string (which is the case in your example).

Also, your last initializer is either wrong or misleading, depending on your intent. What are the values of `val` and `parse_key` supposed to be in the last element? If you want empty strings, then it should be

```
{ "", "", 0, NULL }
```

If you want null pointers, then it should be

```
{ NULL, NULL, 0, NULL }
```

or

```
{ 0, 0, 0, 0 }
```

or even a mere

```
{ 0 }
```

Your current `'\0'` will work as a null-pointer constant, but it is a misleading and strange way to specify a null-pointer constant.

And why you are casing `0` to `void *` for the function pointer member is also unclear. Why? Just write `NULL` or plain `0`. No cast necessary. And if you want a cast, at least cast it to the proper type. Where did `void *` come from?

Comment: @icepack: Last time I checked, C did not allow `{}`. C++ allows `{}`.

Comment: Wasn't aware of it. It works under pre-C99.

Comment: @icepack: Which compiler?

Comment: http://ideone.com/du2Kjk

Comment: @icepack: Oh, OK. This is a non-standard GCC extension. If you run GCC in strictly standard mode (say, under `-std=c90` or `-std=c99`), this will trigger a diagnostic message.

Answer (score 3):

Its because of 2 problems:

```
const char* val;
const char* parse_key;

#define SDP_FILL_STRUCT(a,b) {#a, b, strlen(b), sdp_##a} //strlen(b)
```

**Problem 1:**

`strlen` is not evaluated at the time of compiling .. so the compiler complains .. `strlen` will be only evaluated while running the code.

Note that some compilers might be able to optimize it to a compile-time constant, but that doesn't make it valid to assume that you're allowed to do what you're trying to do.

**Problem 2:** (source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/3025106/1253932 )

In C language the term "constant" refers to literal constants (like 1, 'a', 0xFF and so on) and enum members. Const-qualified objects (of any type) are not constants in C language terminology. They cannot be used in initializers of objects with static storage duration, regardless of their type.

For example, this is NOT a constant

```
const int C = 5; /* `C` is not a constant in C */
```

The above C would be a constant in C++, but it is not a constant in C. So, if you try doing

```
static int j = C; /* ERROR */
```

you will get the same error: an attempt to initialize a static object with a non-constant.