# 25: warning: initializer element is not a constant expression

Tags: c, gcc, constants

GCC gives me the following warning message when trying to compile:

```
las.c:13:18: warning: initializer element is not a constant expression [enabled by default]
 const int ROWS = pow (2, MESH_K);
```

The relevant code portions for this is:

```
 #define MESH_K 10
 #define BUFF_SIZE 30

 const int ROWS = pow (2, MESH_K);
```

I need to use both MESH_K and ROWS at later points in the code. I understand that function calls are probably leading GCC to believe that this is not a constant expression. However given that this call to pow is essentially a constant, is there a better way to implement it (pre-processor macros perhaps?) and eliminate the warning?

I don't mind sacrificing readability for performance in this part of the code, so any and all complex solutions are welcome.

Comment: Not sure if this will work but try `const int ROWS = 1 << MESH_K;` instead.

Comment: Works! And a bonus for a more optimum solution. However, I'd be very grateful if you could help and make this a compile time constant.

Comment: Try this then: `#define POW_2_MESH_K   1 << MESH_K`

Comment: @squeamishossifrage If you could post this as an answer, I'd accept it!

Comment: I just checked the asm code generated by GCC, and it has already performed the required optimizations. So I guess, this is all done now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe your answer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w).

This will compile fine in C++, but not in C.

> It has to do with C language. In C language objects with static
>   storage duration has to be initialized with constant expressions or
>   with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions.
>
> A "large" object is never a constant expression in C, even if the
>   object is declared as const.
>
> Moreover, in C language the term "constant" refers to literal
>   constants (like 1, 'a', 0xFF and so on) and enum members.
>   Const-qualified objects (of any type) are not constants in C language
>   terminology. They cannot be used in initializers of objects with
>   static storage duration, regardless of their type.

Like squeamish says, `const int ROWS = 1 << MESH_K;` will work, but:

```
int test = 10;

const int ROWS = 1 << test;
```

Will NOT work. My guess is that `MESH_K` is pasted into the code as a literal, and therefore resolves to a C constant.

Comment: I went through as many questions as I could find on this topic on SO. However, my question is more about what is a better way to implement this, so that the value of ROWS is for all purposes a constant?

Comment: @darnir And what do you mean by `constant` then? That the value is known at compile-time rather than runtime?

Comment: Yes. Since all the values involved are indeed known at compile time, I thought it would be a good idea to have it computed at compile time itself. I realize that the performance gain is less than trivial, but right now, I'm both trying to shave off miliseconds and wanting to learn something new.

Comment: @darnir I don't think that's the same question you ask in the OP. The problem is ambiguity with the word `constant` as it means something different depending on the context you use it in. For all intents and purposes, it's a `compile-time constant`. Feel free to post it as a separate question, or ask squeamish to post the answer so you can accept it.