# error with C const string declaration

Tags: c, compiler-errors

```
const char* const back_slash = "\\";
const char* const open_braces ="[";

const char* const array[][2] = {

   {
     back_slash,
    open_braces,

    },
};
```

In this case i am getting

error: initializer element is not constant

Can you please help?

Comment: Please have a look on answers given [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w).

Answer (score 3):

In section 6.7.8/4:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static storage duration shall be constant expressions or string literals.

In the C language, the term "constant" refers to literal constants (like 1, 'a', "[" and so on).  `back_slash` and `open_braces` are not compile-time constants.

Answer (score 0):

An array initializer needs to be a comma-separated list of constant expressions; you are using variables.

Answer (score 0):

These are `const`-qualified variables for C, so just variables and not constants in the context of initialization. Use defines to name such literals:

```
#define back_slash "\\"
#define open_braces "["
```

Answer (score 0):

You tried to be too pedantic: C doesn't have real compile time const declarations (with types). One way, to do get the const array part to compile is to declare backslash and open bracket (bracket '[', brace '{') with a #define, unless of course you need them somewhere else. Note about const declarations: one would expect that after 'const int i = 5', i could be used in the code freely and would not appear in the object file. It does, and this can bite you on a small embedded system.