# Why can I not assign a const pointer to a const pointer in a struct?

Tags: c, pointers, gcc, constants

Here is an example below where I try to assign a const pointer to a const pointer in the struct and the compiler won't let me. But I can assign a literal without any problem. I've also tried this case with out any const's and with some const's if you know what I mean, but I still don't see why the compiler is cool with the literals but as issues with the char* in the assignment.

```
const char* cat_surname = "Snack";

typedef struct
{
    const char* first;
    const char* last;
}PET_T;

PET_T dog =
{
        "Rover",    // OK
        "Cateater"  // OK
};

PET_T cat =
{
        "Tasty",    // OK
        cat_surname // ERROR :-(
};
```

I get this compiler error:

> error: initializer element is not constant

Using Arch Linux gcc version 4.8.2 20140206 (prerelease) (GCC)

Comment: `const`-qualified objects are not compile-time constants.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error "initializer element is not constant" when trying to initialize variable with const](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w)

Comment: Suggest `const char cat_surname[] = "Snack"; PET_T cat = {  "Tasty",  cat_surname };`

Comment: you should probably post that as an answer @chux... the rationale is that the addresses of file-scope objects count as constants; so `cat_surname` here decays to `&cat_surname[0]` which the linker is able to fill in.

Comment: I don't know of any logical reason why the standard says that `const`-qualified variables shouldn't be able to have their value used as initializer later on

Comment: @chux thanks, this worked! On a side note I accidentally clicked the up arrow twice(upvote/downvote) and now it won't let me upvote it for good. Sorry about that, but thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid the problem, make `cat_surname` an array of `const char` rather than a pointer to `const char`.

```
const char cat_surname[] = "Snack"; 
PET_T cat = {
  "Tasty",
  cat_surname
};
```

---

Note: The use of `const` does not mean that the object is constant.  It's a bit more like "read-only".  Below, `i` may have different values as `foo()` is called, but the function `foo` may not change it.

```
void foo(const int i) {
  i = 5; // compile time error
}
```

The use of `const` in `const char* cat_surname = "Snack";` does not imply `cat_surname` can not change value.  `const` here means that the data `cat_surname` points to should not be attempted to be change as follows:

```
*cat_surname = 'X'; // bad
```

---

The compiler error "initializer element is not constant" wants a true constant.  An array is that:  the array's first element is *always* at the same address.

@Matt McNabb brings up a good point that the initial value of `cat.last` *could* be `cat_surname`.  I do not have a strong reason why C does not allow that.