# Why can't static variables be initialized with values of other variables?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

What is the reason for this?

```
const int a = 0;
static int b = a * 5;  // compile error
int main()
{
    const int x = 1;
    static int y = x * 10;  // compile error
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025106/257418

Comment: `a` also isn't  a "constant", it's a "variable".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to C standard:

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or thread storage duration
>   shall be constant expressions or string literals.

This is valid C++ code though.

Comment: Specifically `a` is not a constant expression, it actually is a variable. (It would be a "constant" in C++; this limitation is why people use `#define` a lot in C.)