# Why isn't it possible in C to initialize a constant with another constant?

Tags: c, gcc

Compiling the following code with gcc.

**Code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>
const int i = 10;
const int n = i+1;
int main() {
    printf("%i\n", i);
    printf("%i\n", n);
}
```

**Error :**

I get a compile error like below

```
test.c:3:5: error: initializer element is not constant
const int n = i+1;
^
```

Compiling with g++ works just fine and prints 10 and 11.

I used gcc 4.9.2

Comment: Maybe see this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025106/4384927

Answer (score 1):

`const` variable can be initalized with constant values (constant expressions).

---

- In `C`

At compilation time, `i + 1` is not a constant expression.

FWIW, even

```
const int n = i;
```

will give you error, because, even if declared as `const`, `i` cannot be used as *constant expression* to be used as an initalizer to another `const`.

---

- In `C++`

`const` variables are tread as constant expression if they are initialized with constant expressions. So, this is allowed.

Comment: But g++ computes i+1 it at compile time apparently.

Comment: @Thilo Well, in that case, `C` and `C++` are different languages and better treated that way.

Comment: *"const variables are tread as constant expression"* -- *If* they are initialized with constant expressions.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for the correction sir.Updated accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but *WHY*?

Comment: One way to look at this is to interpret the word "const" in these declarations as really meaning "readonly".  The value of the constant on the RHS of the declaration is planted in read-only memory for use at runtime but is *not* entered into the compilers internal tables as a constant that it can look up when used (as opposed to say a #define of a constant, which *is* available to the compiler (or rather pre-processor).

Answer (score 0):

`static` variables need to be initialized with a constant.
A C++ compiler will compile it because in C++ `const` qualified variables are constants. In C, `const` qualified variables are not constant and a C compiler will raise an error.

Comment: But `g++` computes `i+1` it at compile time apparently.

Comment: @Thilo g++ is a C++ compiler and in C++ the rules for constants are different. In C++ a constant can be initialized with a value evaluated at runtime. Const in c++ means that once initialized you cannot change its value any more.

Comment: @rozina: But that is not the case here. In this case (for C++), `i + 1` is evaluated at compile time. `i`, `i + 1`, and `n` are all compile time constant expressions in this code.

Comment: This is wrong. It has nothing to do with const. extern and static variables are initialised before main () starts, and their values must be constant expressions. In C, unlike C++, extern const variables don't count as "constant" as far as "constant expressions" are concerned. You can initialise a const local variable any way you like.