# Pebble SDK: Store color as a variable

Tags: c, variables, colors, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk

I'm make Pebble Time versions of my watchfaces.

I want to be able to set a color variable that will hold a color depending on whether the Pebble Time is used or the Pebble OG is used.

I know you can do this:

```
#ifdef PBL_COLOR
  window_set_background_color(s_main_window, GColorDukeBlue);
#else
  window_set_background_color(s_main_window, GColorBlack);
#endif
```

But I don't want to apply this to the 50 different elements that I want to change the color to.  Could I set a variable called `myColor` at the start of my program at the start of my program and set it to GColorPastelYellow if it's using the Basalt hardware and set it to GColorWhite if it's the Aplite hardware?

I have this right now:

```
static GColor *myColor;

#ifdef PBL_COLOR
  myColor = GColorPastelYellow;
#else
  myColor = GColorWhite;
#endif
```

Unforuntately that doesn't work :/  Anyone have a solution to accomplishing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were probably getting an error because `window_set_background_color` expects a `GColor` not a `GColor *`, but you still can't make `GColor` static. A great explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w).

You can however use `#define` to your advantage. Like:

```
#ifdef PBL_COLOR
  #define MYCOLOR GColorPastelYellow
#else
  #define MYCOLOR GColorWhite
#endif
```

Comment: Thanks Kirby!!  Not too used to all of this just yet but I'm getting there...  PS:  really liked your talk that you gave in presenting the timeline :)