# Why it is allowed to initialize static variable with non const here?

Tags: c, gcc, initialization, constants, static-variables

I was reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w/3025106?noredirect=1#comment49956032_3025106). The first answer by @Andrei T says that

> A "large" object is never a constant expression in C, even if the
>   object is declared as const. Const-qualified objects (of any type) are
>   not constants in C language terminology. They cannot be used in
>   initializers of objects with static storage duration, regardless of
>   their type.
>
> For example, this is NOT a constant
>
> ```
> const int N = 5; /* `N` is not a constant in C */
> ```
>
> The above N would be a constant in C++, but it is not a constant in C.
>   So, if you try doing
>
> ```
> static int j = N; /* ERROR */
> ```
>
> you will get the same error: an attempt to initialize a static object
>   with a non-constant

I agree with his answer. I also tried a simple example like following on gcc 4.8.2 & 4.9.2 & it gives compiler errors as I expected:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    const int a=5;
    static int b=a;
    printf("%d",b);
}
```

But When I tried it on `ideone.com` it compiles & runs fine and gives expected outcome. See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/lx4Xed). Also, on codeblocks 13.12 IDE (gcc 4.7.1) this program runs fine. So, Is it compiler bug or gcc extension? What combination of compiler options `ideone` uses under the hood? So, how & why it compiles in `ideone`? What is the reason?

Comment: I suggest you accept Grzegorz Szpetkowski's answer. I've submitted a gcc bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66618

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the ideone *likely* invokes `gcc` with `-O` option (optimization level 1). This is the case even for older versions of `gcc` (mine is 4.4.7):

```
$ gcc -ansi main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6: error: initializer element is not constant
$ gcc -ansi -O main.c
$ echo $?
0
```

What's interesting here is that with `-pedantic` it is working properly again and required diagnostic message is present (tested only with 4.4.7, <sub>[see Keith's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962512/why-it-is-allowed-to-initialize-static-variable-with-non-const-here#comment49958078_30962954)</sub>):

```
gcc -ansi -pedantic -O main.c 
main.c: In function ‘main’:
main.c:6: error: initializer element is not constant
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: I can confirm this behavior on my own system; `-O` (or `-O1`, `-O2`, `-O3`) causes gcc not to diagnose the error. That's a bug in gcc. The use of a non-constant expression to initialize a static object is a constraint violation, requiring a diagnostic. That diagnostic may be a non-fatal warning, but some diagnostic message is mandatory. And I *don't* see the error with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -O main.c` (gcc 4.8.4).

Comment: And gcc's behavior is inconsistent. It permits the use of `a` as an initializer for a `static` object, but not in a case label.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a gcc speciality. Compiling with `-std=c89` or `-pedantic` reports the error.

Since in all C standards this is a constraint violation, not giving a diagnostic for that case makes gcc without one of the `-std=c??` options a non-conforming compiler.

Comment: Mentioning that extension would be helpful.

Comment: I can't find a set of options that causes gcc *not* to report an error (versions 4.1.2 and 4.8.4).

Comment: I searched [GCC C-extensions list](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html) and found nothing regarding this.

Comment: @haccks, it doesn't seem that they document this in the place that you would expect. And actually since this in C this a constraint violation, this isn't even an extension but makes the gcc compiler without specifying one of the standards non-conforming.

Comment: Jens, are you able to compile the code in the question using gcc with *any* set of options? I haven't been able to.

Comment: Update: As Grzegorz Szpetkowski's answer says, gcc's `-O` option inhibits diagnosis of this error -- even with `-std=cNN -pedantic`.

Comment: I've submitted a gcc bug report: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66618