# MSVC "error C2099: initializer is not a constant" with value composed of other constants, only on C

Tags: c, visual-c++

I have some code involving `static const uint64_t` values I am trying to use as a bitset. The issue is, when I compile it with MSVC, I get the error `"initializer is not a constant"`. However, when I compile the code with MSVC and rename the file as `.cpp`, it works fine. Also, If I compile it with gcc on windows 10, it also works fine.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// A 52 card deck can be represented in a bit set.
typedef uint64_t PokerCardSet;

// individal cards
// -------------------------------
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_A = (PokerCardSet)1 << 0;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_2 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 1;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_3 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 2;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_4 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 3;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_5 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 4;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_6 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 5;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_7 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 6;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_8 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 7;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_9 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 8;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_10 = (PokerCardSet)1 << 9;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_J = (PokerCardSet)1 << 10;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_Q = (PokerCardSet)1 << 11;
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_K = (PokerCardSet)1 << 12;

static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_SUIT = HEARTS_A |
                                        HEARTS_2 |
                                        HEARTS_3 |
                                        HEARTS_4 |
                                        HEARTS_5 |
                                        HEARTS_6 |
                                        HEARTS_7 |
                                        HEARTS_8 |
                                        HEARTS_9 |
                                        HEARTS_10 |
                                        HEARTS_J |
                                        HEARTS_Q |
                                        HEARTS_K;
```

What I think should be ok is that, `HEARTS_SUIT` is composed only of other constants. So I am not sure why I am getting this only with MSVC and compiling it as a C file.

This is the exact error I get

```
poker.c(69): error C2099: initializer is not a constant
```

line 69 is the `HEARTS_SUIT` line, but I took away some other code that gets the same error so it's faster to read and comprehend.

My MSVC version is:

```
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.16.27032.1 for x64
```

IS there a way around this for MSVC and C? Or would I have to switch the card values to be macros?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962512/why-it-is-allowed-to-initialize-static-variable-with-non-const-here.  It is "permissive" behaviour of GCC and strictly non-conforming.  Note that C compilation on MSVC is ISO C90 - although that is not specifically the issue here, but will lead to a great deal of modern C code not compiling in any case.

Comment: @Clifford Makes sense, but why does it work with MSVC with a `.cpp` file with the same code? Does MSVC use a higher default C++ standard than it does for C?

Comment: Because C++ is a different language, and the semantics of const differ between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/const) website (though in their section on the `C` language):

> const semantics apply to lvalue expressions only; whenever a const
>   lvalue expression is used in context that does not require an lvalue,
>   its const qualifier is lost (note that volatile qualifier, if present,
>   isn't lost).

And, from the *actual* [C11 Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (Section 6.7.3):

> The properties associated with qualiﬁed types are meaningful only for
>   expressions that are lvalues.

In your expression:

```
static const PokerCardSet HEARTS_SUIT = HEARTS_A |
...
```

`HEARTS_A` is not ***required to be*** an lvalue, so the `const` qualifier is lost.

EDIT: Note that, in `C++`, there is no such "qualifier loss" (whatever version of the Standard is used). Further, as noted in the comment by **Clifford**, and discussed in the [Stack Overflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30962512/why-it-is-allowed-to-initialize-static-variable-with-non-const-here) he links, the `gcc` compiler is non-conforming in this respect.

Comment: This does not answer the question why this works on GCC and not on MSVC compiler. (gcc on windows)

Comment: Also losing the `const` qualifier is a different compiler error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c3848?view=vs-2019

Comment: @JoshWeinstein I've added an 'EDIT' section to (hopefully) clarify your concerns, as well as the comments you and others made in the question.

Comment: that's fair. This is enough to warrant me going with c++ for this part of my project anyways