# Strcmp causes segfault

Tags: c, pointers, casting, pointer-to-pointer

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int my_compare(const void * a, const void * b);

int main()
{
    char s[][80] =
        { "gxydyv", "gdyvjv", "lfdtvr", "ayfdbk", "sqkpge", "axkoev", "wdjitd", "pyrefu", "mdafyu",
 "zdgjjf", "awhlff", "dqupga", "qoprcn", "axjyfb", "hfrgjf", "dvhhhr" };
    int i;
    puts("#Before:#");
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        puts(s[i]);
    qsort(s, 16, sizeof *s, my_compare);
    putchar('\n');
    puts("#After:#");
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i++)
        puts(s[i]);
    return 0;
}

int my_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(*(char **)a, *(char **)b);
}
```

Here is the output:

```
#Before:#
gxydyv
gdyvjv
lfdtvr
ayfdbk
sqkpge
axkoev
wdjitd
pyrefu
mdafyu
zdgjjf
awhlff
dqupga
qoprcn
axjyfb
hfrgjf
dvhhhr
Segmentation fault
```

I also notice that the prototype of strcmp is:
int strcmp(const char *s1,const char *s2);

I suppose that the type of a and b in my_compare is "pointer to array-of-char". As a result, *(char **)a is a "pointer to char", which is exactly what strcmp expects.

So where is the problem?

Comment: `qsort(s, 16, sizeof *s, my_compare);` and `int my_compare(const void *a, const void *b)` or to eliminate hardcoding values: `qsort(s, sizeof s/sizeof *s, sizeof *s, my_compare);`

Comment: Is it me or did the original question try to loop through 80 values when there were significantly fewer?  My mind and eyes might be playing tricks though.

Comment: You are correct -- the original questions keeps changing...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change:

```
return strcmp(*(char **) a, *(char **) b);
```

To:

```
return strcmp(a,b);
```

You had an extra level of pointer dereferencing that was incorrect and that's why you got the segfault.  That is, you were passing the `char` *values* and *not* the `char` *pointers* [which got masked with the cast].

Note: no need to cast from `void *` here.

---

**UPDATE:**

In reponse to your question, yes, because of the way you defined `s` and the `qsort` call.

Your original `my_compare` would have been fine if you had done:

```
char *s[] = { ... };
```

And changed your `qsort` call to:

```
qsort(s, 16, sizeof(char *), my_compare);
```

---

To summarize, here are two ways to do it

```
int
main()
{
    char s[][80] = { ... }

    qsort(s, 16, 80, my_compare);

    return 0;
}

int
my_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(a,b);
}
```

This is a bit cleaner [uses less space in array]:

```
int
main()
{
    char *s[] = { ... }

    qsort(s, 16, sizeof(char *), my_compare);

    return 0;
}

int
my_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    return strcmp(*(char **) a,*(char **) b);
}
```

---

**UPDATE #2:**

To answer your second question:  **No**

None of these even compile:

```
return strcmp((char ()[80])a,(char ()[80])b);
return strcmp(*(char ()[80])a,*(char ()[80])b);
return strcmp((char [][80])a,(char [][80])b);
return strcmp(*(char [][80])a,*(char [][80])b);
```

But, even if the did, they would be logically incorrect.  The following does *not* compile either, but is logically closer to what `qsort` is passing:

```
return strcmp((char [80])a,(char [80])b);
```

But, when a function *passes* something defined as `char x[80]` it's just the same as `char *x`, so `qsort` is passing `char *` [disguised as `void *`].

A side note: Using `char *s[]` is far superior. It allows for arbitrary length strings.  The other form `char s[][80]` will actually fail if a given string exceeds [or is exactly] 80 chars.

---

I think it's important for you to understand:

1. Arrays are *call by reference*.
2. The *interchangeability* of arrays and pointers.

The following two are equivalent:

```
char *
strary(char p[])
{

    for (;  *p != 0;  ++p);

    return p;
}

char *
strptr(char *p)
{

    for (;  *p != 0;  ++p);

    return p;
}
```

Consider the following [outer] definitions:

```
char x[] = { ... };
char *x = ...;
```

*Either* of these two may be passed to `strary` and/or `strptr` in *any* of the following forms [total of 20]:

```
strXXX(x);
strXXX(x + 0);
strXXX(&x[0]);

strXXX(x + 1);
strXXX(&x[1]);
```

Also, see my recent answer here: [Issue implementing dynamic array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358758/issue-implementing-dynamic-array-of-structures/33358829#33358829)

Comment: You mean the a and b given to my_compare by qsort are pointers to char, other than pointers to array-of-char?

Comment: For char s[][80], maybe you should use int my_compare(const void *a, const void *b)
{
 return strcmp(*(char (*)[80])a, *(char (*)[80])b);
}

Answer (score 0):

You can just cast it to a const char *, it should work now:

```
int my_compare(const void *a, const void *b) {
    return strcmp((const char *)a, (const char *)b);
}
```

And also you should add:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Comment: If he has a `void *` there is no need to cast in C.