# C - I don't understand why this code isn't outputting the values I chose. (pointers)

Tags: c, function, pointers

I'm supposed to recieve and print 3 values but using pointers and functions for each part. arrPointer is the pointer to the array, it goes to the getVar function recieves 3 inputs from the user, puts them in an array and returns the address of the array to main. Then using that address it prints the 3 variables. Or at least it's supposed to. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getVar()
{
    int *arrPointer;
    int values[3];

    printf("Enter 3 values:\n");
    scanf("%d", &values[0]);
    scanf("%d", &values[1]);
    scanf("%d", &values[2]);

    arrPointer = values;
    return(arrPointer);
}

void printFunc(int *arrPointer)
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
       printf("%d", *arrPointer);
        arrPointer++;

        }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int *arrPointer;
    arrPointer = getVar();

    printf("The numbers entered in order are: ");
    printFunc(arrPointer);
}
```

Comment: Your compiler should have told you that the function `getVar()` is used inconsistently: it is declared to return an `int`, but returns an `int*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set your pointer to the address of an array that is in the *stack* frame of `getVar`.

When that function returns, the stack frame is popped and those values go out of scope. (i.e. they can/should no longer be accessed).

When you call `printf` from `main`, the call will reuse that stack memory space previously used by `getVar`. Likewise, for `printFunc`.

So, whatever they use it for, it overwrites/corrupts the values that where created by `getVar`

There are two ways to remedy this:

1. Have `getVar` do a `malloc`
2. Have `main` pass the address of an array [in `main`'s stack frame] to `getVar`

For a more elaborate explanation of pointers and arrays, see my answer here: [Issue implementing dynamic array of structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358758/issue-implementing-dynamic-array-of-structures/33358829#33358829)

---

Here is the version with `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int *
getVar()
{
    int *values = malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

    printf("Enter 3 values:\n");
    scanf("%d", &values[0]);
    scanf("%d", &values[1]);
    scanf("%d", &values[2]);

    return values;
}

void
printFunc(int *arrPointer)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d", *arrPointer);
        arrPointer++;

    }
    printf("\n");
}

int
main()
{
    int *arrPointer;

    arrPointer = getVar();

    printf("The numbers entered in order are: ");
    printFunc(arrPointer);

    free(arrPointer);

    return 0;
}
```

---

Here is the version that uses's a stack variable from `main`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
getVar(int *values)
{

    printf("Enter 3 values:\n");
    scanf("%d", &values[0]);
    scanf("%d", &values[1]);
    scanf("%d", &values[2]);
}

void
printFunc(int *arrPointer)
{
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d", *arrPointer);
        arrPointer++;

    }
    printf("\n");
}

int
main()
{
    int arr[3];

    getVar(arr);

    printf("The numbers entered in order are: ");
    printFunc(arr);
}
```

---

**UPDATE:**

> is it possible to return an array or more than 1 variable from a function?

Yes, in a way, but the *caller* must pass down a place for the extra values.

In the second example above, another way to look at it is that the *caller* (i.e. `main`) is requesting *three* values from `getVar` and provides space for these values in the array.

Another way is for the caller to pass down *multiple* pointer values that show where to return the values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void
getVar(int *val,float *fval)
{

    printf("Enter 2 values:\n");
    scanf("%d", val);
    scanf("%f", fval);
}

int
main()
{
    int val;
    float fval;

    getVar(&val,&fval);
}
```

But, passing a pointer argument can get tedious if more than two values are desired.

So, in that case, we can pass down the address of a `struct` that can have as many return values as we wish:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct values {
    int val;
    float fval;
    int count;
    int rval;
};

void
getVar(struct values *ret)
{

    printf("Enter 3 values:\n");
    scanf("%d", &ret->val);
    scanf("%f", &ret->fval);
    scanf("%d", &ret->count);
    ret->rval = rand() % ret->count;
}

int
main()
{
    struct values val;

    getVar(&val);
}
```

Note that we could also use the `malloc` method combined with the `struct`. That is, `getVar` does a `struct values *ret = malloc(sizeof(struct values));` and then returns this pointer (after filling in the struct).

Comment: Oh I see! I have one more question, is it possible to return an array or more than 1 variable from a function?

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems:

1. The `values[3]` array is declared in the `getVar()` function. After
   the function ends, the space that was allocated for `int values[3]`
   goes out of scope. The solution of this problem is to allocate
   memory dinamically:  `int* values = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);`
2. The return type of the function `getVar()` should be of pointer type. Change `int getVar()` to `int* getVar()`

Answer (score 0):

to save values to an array you will need to set each position to the array with a variable(int), as you did. But you can't do arrPointer = values.
Also you need to pass the pointers to the functions, not to declare them again.
Hope this helps and works

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int getVar(int *values[])
{
    printf("Enter 3 values:\n");
    scanf("%d", &values[0]);
    scanf("%d", &values[1]);
    scanf("%d", &values[2]);

    return values;
}

void printFunc(int *values[])
{
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i<3; i++)
    {
       printf("%d", values[i]);


        }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{
    int *arrPointer;
    int *values[3];
    getVar(values);

    printf("The numbers entered in order are: ");
    printFunc(values);
}
```