# Why in a bidimensional static array arr, arr is the same thing as *arr

Tags: c

I know that in a bidimensional static array arr, arr is the same with arr[0], &arr[0], &arr[0][0], but I can't find why this also happens with *arr

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358758/issue-implementing-dynamic-array-of-structures/33358829#33358829 It has an extended explanation of how to access arrays vs pointers in all forms.

Comment: `*arr` and `arr[0]` are defined as meaning the same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets take a look at a simple two "dimensional" array (array of arrays) and how it looks like in memory.

First the array:

```
int a[2][2];
```

And how it looks like in memory (with some pointers):

```
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| a[0][0] | a[0][1] | a[1][0] | a[1][1] |
+---------+---------+---------+---------+
^
|
&a
|
&a[0]
|
&a[0][0]
```

Looking at this it should be easy to understand why the pointers are the same.

To continue don't forget that all arrays can decay to a pointer to its first element. That is, for the array `a` above, then `a` is equal to `&a[0]`. That means `*a` is equal to `*&a[0]`, which since the `*` and `&` operators cancel each other out, will be equal to `a[0]`. And since `a[0]` is an array it will decay to a pointer to its first element which is equal to `&a[0][0]`. That is, `*a` is equal to `&a[0][0]`.