# What is the difference between extern variables in C and C++?

Tags: c++, c, extern

`b.c` fails to compile but `b.cpp` can be compiled. I don't quite understand the difference of extern between C and C++. Could anybody help explain why `b.c` does not work but `b.cpp` does? Thanks.

```
$ cat b.c 

extern int b;
int a = b;
$ gcc -g -Wall -pedantic -c -o b.o b.c
b.c:4:9: error: initializer element is not a compile-time constant
int a = b;
        ^
1 error generated.
$ cat b.cpp 

extern int b;
int a = b;
$ g++ -g -Wall -pedantic -c -o b.o b.cpp
$ ls -g b.o 
-rw-r--r-- 1 staff 2640 Jan  5 10:22 b.o
```

Comment: If I recall correctly, C does not support runtime initialization like that of a global variable.

Answer (score 6):

There is no significant difference between `extern` variables in C and C++.  What is different, is the rule for valid initializers.  In C, the initializer of a variable with static storage duration [must be a compile time constant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34450315/771073).  In C++, it can be pretty much any expression (including a complicated function call).

Answer (score 5):

It's not an extern issue.

[Error "initializer element is not constant" when trying to initialize variable with const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w)

In C language objects with static storage duration have to be initialized with constant expressions or with aggregate initializers containing constant expressions.

Answer (score 4):

It is not about extern variables. In C variables with static storage have to have constant initializers. In C++ they may have almost any. The difference is:  C++ objects have constructors and the object can be initialized almost any way (for example by the method or function call).

in C++ this kind of initialisation is possible:

```
#include <string.h>

volatile char s[] = "sdfsasdf";

size_t size = strlen((char *)s);
```

Comment: Only objects of class type have constructors. A `size_t` is not a class and does not have a constructor. The rest of what you say is true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit yes it was simplification as the OPs question shows that he just started learning C, it is of course static initialisation and destruction in C++. But it does in the fact exactly the same

Comment: But it's not a "simplification", it's a wrong statement ;) Let's try to avoid teaching new starters falsehoods right out of the gate.