# FILE * ..=stdout : Error initializer element is not constant

Tags: c, linux, suse

My C code was as following:

```
[Linux:/si/usr/hrl]vi test.c    

#include <stdio.h>

FILE * hw = stdout;

int main(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

When I compile on SUSE , it make the error like that:

```
[Linux:/si/usr/hrl]cc test.c -o test
test.c:3: error: initializer element is not constant
```

I have a look for the header file `stdio.h` and find that `stdout` seems to have be defined as a constant. So why the error produce?By the way, I compile the same code on AIX ,it results of success.

Comment: Hum. How is `stdout` defined in your C standard library implementation? What it its type?

Comment: I doesn't look so careful.Maybe it's that `extern struct _IO_FILE *stdout;         /* Standard output stream.  */`.  By the way , I use `c++` and compile, it compiled successful.

Comment: @hrl This question is highly relevant to the point some would probably say your question here is a duplicate of it:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w

Answer (score 7):

The standard does not require `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr` to be constants.

The draft n1256 for C99 says in 7.19.1 Input/output <stdio.h>

> The header  declares ...
>   ...
>   TMP_MAX
>   which expands to an integer **constant expression** ...
>
> stderr
>   stdin
>   stdout
>   which are **expressions** of type ‘‘pointer to FILE’’ ...

(emphasize mine)

It is explicitely stated that some other values are constant, whereas nothing is said for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`

So you must put initialization in main:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * hw;

int main(void)
{
        hw = stdout;
        ...
        return 0;
}
```

In AIX standard library, `stdout` happens to be a constant, but it is just an implementation detail and you cannot rely on that, as it could break in any newer version.

But you should not rely either on `stdout` being a variable (nor even a lvalue), because it is also an implementation detail in GCC library.

---

If you cannot change much of your code, and just need a GCC hack to make it compilable, you could try to use the gcc *constructor attribute* extension.

Extract from [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.3.0/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes)

> 6.31 Declaring Attributes of Functions
>
> In GNU C, you declare certain things about functions called in your program which help the compiler optimize function calls and check your code more carefully.
>
> The keyword `__attribute__` allows you to specify special attributes when making a declaration. This keyword is followed by an attribute specification inside double parentheses. The following attributes are currently defined for functions on all targets: ... ,**constructor**, ...
>   ...
>   The constructor attribute causes the function to be called automatically before execution enters main () ...

So you could use:

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * hw;

void initHw(void) __attribute__((constructor)) {
    hw = stdout;
}

int main(void)
{
        return 0;
}
```

But **BEWARE**: it is a gcc extension, meaning that your code is **not** correct C.

Comment: I know your edit is correct.But I want to seek a way to compile it successfully without initializing it in `main()`.Because that was a little pieces of the program which I should transplant to Suse from AIX. It is hard to me to modify the real code as you say.