# Initialize a struct with data from an array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I'd like to keep my keywords in a struct:

```
typedef const char* label;
const struct keywords_t
{
    label init;
    label moveUnit;
} keywords;
```

But I'd like to be able to check whether a keyword is valid with a for loop, so I tried to initialize the struct like this:

```
const label allowed_keywords[] =
{
    "INIT",
    "MOVE"
};

const struct keywords_t keywords =
{
    allowed_keywords[0],
    allowed_keywords[1]
};
```

This gives me an

```
error: initializer element is not constant
```

What am I doing wrong? The whole array is constant, though.

Comment: Clang accepts it without complaint.  What compiler are you using?  I think it's not portable; see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3025106/4323

Comment: @JohnZwinck clang++ accept it, but not clang.

Comment: Don't `typedef` pointers!

Comment: @JohnZwinck: This will not work for C, but maybe for C++. C does not have symbolic constants other than _enum constants_.

Comment: @Olaf why? (15 chars)

Comment: You got the answer from your compiler already. C and C++ are different languages. Identical syntax&grammer does not imply identical semantics.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C `const`variables are not constants, they are simply variables that cannot be changed. Thus their value cannot be used in constant expressions, like in struct initializer.

One work-around could be to use preprocessor defines for initializers:

```
#define KEYWORD_INIT   "INIT"
#define KEYWORD_MOVE   "MOVE"

const label allowed_keywords[] =
{
    KEYWORD_INIT,
    KEYWORD_MOVE
};

const struct keywords_t keywords = 
{
    KEYWORD_INIT,
    KEYWORD_MOVE
};
```

Other approach could be to use combination of enumeration and array:

```
typedef enum {
    KEYWORD_INIT,
    KEYWORD_MOVE
} label;

const char * const keyword_strings[] = {
    "INIT",
    "MOVE"
};

const struct keywords_t keywords =
{
    KEYWORD_INIT,
    KEYWORD_MOVE
};

// Getting keyword string would be like this:
// keyword_strings[keywords.moveUnit]
```

Comment: "cannot be changed" -> "**must not** be changed". The const-ness is not necessarily enforced by the compiler, but guaranteed by the programmer.

Answer (score 1):

I might be the best resource for this, but both Arrays and Structs are simple memory mapping tools.

An array of `char *` and a struct containing the same number of `char *` should have the same memory structure and the same memory footprint.

So, in practice, all you need is to cast the array into the struct rather then anything else (this will also save you memory, although this is probably not so important).

i.e.

```
const label allowed_keywords[] =
{
    "INIT",
    "MOVE"
};

typedef const char* label;
const struct keywords_t
{
    label init;
    label moveUnit;
};

// struct keywords_t * keywords = (struct keywords_t *) allowed_keywords;

#define keywords ((struct keywords_t *) allowed_keywords)
```

A few things:

1. this needs to be tested.
2. I would avoid using the `_t` for the `struct keywords_t`, as `_t` is reserved for POSIX types. I use `_s` for structs and `_pt` for pointers... but that's up to you.