# C - Set the value of a static variable if unset

Tags: c, gcc, static-variables

I have the following code snippet:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void read(int a[ ],int n)
{
      static int p=n;
      if(n!=0)
       {
           printf("enter element %d: ",p-n);
           scanf("%d",&a[p-n]);
           read(a,n-1);
        }
}
int main()
{
   int a[10],n;
   printf("enter n: ");
   scanf("%d",&n);
   read(a,n);
}
```

I keep getting  the `error: initializer element is not constant`. 
Isn't n constant by the time the function compiles?

Edit:
Problem: How to set the value of a static variable(if it isn't set) within a function?

Comment: It is because you can't initialize a static variable with another variable, only constant values that can be determined at compile time.

Comment: The answer is no. It's not constant, is a variable, passed to a function. In C you can have a compile time constant by using `#define n 10`. Also, there are several post on this argument, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w

Comment: `static int p=n;` --> `static int p; if(!p) p = n;`

Comment: Thanks guys, I solved it BLUEPIXY's way.

Answer (score 4):

It is because you can't initialize a `static` variable with another **variable**, only with **constant values** that can be determined at **compile time**, such as macros, literals, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Most certainly not; how does the compiler know what value is going to be assigned to n at compile time?

Answer (score 2):

> I keep getting the error: initializer element is not constant.

Global and static variables can only be initialized with constant expressions known at compile time.

> Isn't n constant by the time the function compiles?

The answer is no. The n stores value received from `stdin`. Therefore, it receives the value during run-time.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit : Solution is assign `p` to `n` only if `p` is unset**

Solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
static int p;
void read(int a[ ],int n)
{
    //p=n; //to change n on each call 
    if(!p) p = n; //to change n only if p is unset
      if(n!=0)
       {
           printf("enter element %d: ",p-n);
           scanf("%d",&a[p-n]);
           read(a,n-1);
        }
}
int main()
{
    int a[10],n;
    printf("enter n: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    read(a,n);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but that was not what I needed, because p takes a new n everycall.

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Don't you want p to get n value each loop?

Comment: Nope, I wanted it to take only the first n, so p-n is used as index for the array.

Comment: @user6019827 That wasn't clear in the question. Edited the answer. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: @user6019827 also read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: The original version of the question had capital letters at the start of most of the lines — probably due to a tablet or phone doing case-conversion.  The reported error message, though, is not consistent with having problems with case of letters.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler the question was unclear earlier. Now the problem statement was edited & accordingly the code above works.

Comment: I agree the original was unclear; my comment was documenting to those who come after why you don't deserve down-votes for what is no longer a visible problem (because the question has been edited).  However, your diagnosis was not consistent with the compiler error message.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The answer has been edited accordingly now.

Comment: Your code has changed the location of `p` (it's no longer hidden in a function) which could affect the behaviour of other code — if there was any.  It also would make it possible to use the function for more than loading a single array (because you could reset `p` from another function); the existing design doesn't allow that.  I would need to spend time studying the code more to say more; but it's an hour or more after bedtime here and the code isn't sufficiently exciting to warrant the effort.

Comment: I believe in answering to the question asked and the current answer is what the user wanted.