# error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v61.1.0`

Tags: rust, rust-cargo, oniguruma

#### error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v61.1.0`

I am compiling the rust program https://github.com/trishume/syntect by running `make packs`. However it throws the error:

```
$ make packs
cargo run --example gendata -- synpack testdata/Packages assets/default_newlines.packdump assets/default_nonewlines.packdump
   Compiling onig_sys v61.1.0
error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v61.1.0`
process didn't exit successfully: `D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-523c993a9ee13532\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)

...

--- stderr
DIST_NAME: onig
DIST_VERSION: 6.1.1
DIST_LICENSE: BSD
DIST_AUTHOR: K.Kosako
DIST_MAINTAINER: K.Kosako
DIST_URL: https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma
DIST_DESC: Oniguruma is a regular expressions library.
DIST_DEPENDS:
thread 'main' panicked at '
command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.21\src\lib.rs:605
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.

make: *** [packs] Error 101
```

Why the https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma is not compiling?

I ran `cargo build -vv` and got this most all the log:

```
D:\syntect>cargo build -vv
       Fresh num-traits v0.1.37
       Fresh winapi-build v0.1.1
       Fresh pkg-config v0.3.9
       Fresh gcc v0.3.45
       Fresh regex-syntax v0.4.0
       Fresh num-integer v0.1.33
       Fresh cmake v0.1.21
       Fresh num-iter v0.1.33
       Fresh lazy_static v0.2.4
       Fresh winapi v0.2.8
       Fresh yaml-rust v0.3.5
       Fresh serde v0.8.23
       Fresh bitflags v0.7.0
       Fresh num v0.1.37
       Fresh xml-rs v0.3.6
       Fresh rustc-serialize v0.3.23
       Fresh bitflags v0.8.0
       Fresh fnv v1.0.5
       Fresh serde v0.9.11
       Fresh kernel32-sys v0.2.2
       Fresh byteorder v1.0.0
       Fresh bincode v0.6.1
   Compiling onig_sys v61.1.0
       Fresh same-file v0.1.3
       Fresh libc v0.2.21
     Running `D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-523c993a9ee13532\build-scrip
t-build`
       Fresh byteorder v0.5.3
       Fresh walkdir v1.0.7
       Fresh miniz-sys v0.1.9
       Fresh time v0.1.36
       Fresh flate2 v0.2.17
       Fresh chrono v0.2.25
       Fresh plist v0.1.2
running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\Professional\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\onig_sys-61.1.0\\oniguruma" "-G" "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" "-
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\\syntect\\target\\debug\\build\\onig_sys-d633e
4c1e0d45051\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Rele
ase"
DIST_NAME: onig
DIST_VERSION: 6.1.1
DIST_LICENSE: BSD
DIST_AUTHOR: K.Kosako
DIST_MAINTAINER: K.Kosako
DIST_URL: https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma
DIST_DESC: Oniguruma is a regular expressions library.
DIST_DEPENDS:
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/syntect/target/debug/build/onig_sys-d633e
4c1e0d45051/out/build
running: "cmake" "--build" "." "--target" "install" "--config" "Release" "--"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.24723.2
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 17/03/2017 15:41:57.
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\instal
l.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\instal
l.vcxproj" (1) is building "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d450
51\out\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  Checking Build System
  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/syntect/target/debug/build/onig_sys-d6
33e4c1e0d45051/out/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\ou
t\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\instal
l.vcxproj" (1) is building "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d450
51\out\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\ALL_BU
ILD.vcxproj" (3) is building "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d4
5051\out\build\onig.vcxproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "onig.dir\Release\onig.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/onig_sys-61.1.0/oniguruma/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/syntect/target/debug/build/onig_sys-d6
33e4c1e0d45051/out/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
ClCompile:
  F:\VisualStudio2015\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /I"D:\syntect\target\debug\build
\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build" /I"C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma" /nologo /W1 /WX- /O2 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
/D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"onig.dir\Release\\" /Fd"onig.dir\Release\onig.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\
Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c"
  regenc.c
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): warning C4273: 'OnigEncDefaultCharEncoding': inconsistent dll linkage [D
:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(227): note: see previous definition of 'OnigEncDefaultCharEncoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): error C2099: initializer is not a constant [D:\User\\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(36): warning C4273: 'onigenc_init': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(343): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_init'
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(345): note: see previous definition of 'onig_initialize_encoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(53): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_default_encoding': inconsistent dll linkage
[D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(349): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_default_encoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(59): warning C4273: 'onigenc_set_default_encoding': inconsistent dll linkage
[D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(347): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_set_default_encoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(66): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_head': inconsistent dll li
nkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcx
proj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(359): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_he
ad'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(77): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_head_with_prev': inconsist
ent dll linkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\buil
d\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(353): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_he
ad_with_prev'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(92): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_prev_char_head': inconsistent dll linkage [D
:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(355): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_prev_char_head'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(101): warning C4273: 'onigenc_step_back': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\User\D
ropbox\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(338): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_step_back'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(127): warning C4273: 'onigenc_step': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\User\Dropbo
x\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(222): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_step'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(137): warning C4273: 'onigenc_strlen': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\User\Drop
box\Applications\SoftwareVersioning\SublimeText\Data\Packages\ObjectBeautifier\source\libraries\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(361): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_strlen'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(150): warning C4273: 'onigenc_strlen_null': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(363): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_strlen_null'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(175): warning C4273: 'onigenc_str_bytelen_null': inconsistent dll linkage [D:
\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(365): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_str_bytelen_null'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(197): warning C4273: 'OnigEncAsciiToLowerCaseTable': inconsistent dll linkage
 [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]

  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(228): note: see previous definition of 'OnigEncAsciiToLowerCaseTable'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(269): warning C4273: 'OnigEncAsciiCtypeTable': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\U
ser\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(230): note: see previous definition of 'OnigEncAsciiCtypeTable'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(304): warning C4273: 'OnigEncISO_8859_1_ToLowerCaseTable': inconsistent dll l
inkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vc
xproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(216): note: see previous definition of 'OnigEncISO_8859_1_ToLowerCaseTable'


"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\install.vcxpro
j" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxp
roj" (default target) (3) ->
"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj"
(default target) (4) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): error C2099: initializer is not a constant [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]

    45 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.85
thread 'main' panicked at '
command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.21\src\lib.rs:605
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v61.1.0`
process didn't exit successfully: `D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-523c993
a9ee13532\build-script-build` (exit code: 101)
--- stdout
running: "cmake" "C:\\Users\\Professional\\.cargo\\registry\\src\\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\\onig_sys-61.1.0\\oniguruma" "-G" "Visual Studio 14 2015 Win64" "-DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF" "-
DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=D:\\User\\syntect\\target\\debug\\build\\onig_sys-d633e
4c1e0d45051\\out" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE= /nologo /MD" "-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Rele
ase"
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: D:/syntect/target/debug/build/onig_sys-d633e
4c1e0d45051/out/build
running: "cmake" "--build" "." "--target" "install" "--config" "Release" "--"
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.24723.2
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Build started 17/03/2017 15:41:57.
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\instal
l.vcxproj" on node 1 (default targets).
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\instal
l.vcxproj" (1) is building "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d450
51\out\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Creating "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  Checking Build System
  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/syntect/target/debug/build/onig_sys-d6
33e4c1e0d45051/out/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
FinalizeBuildStatus:
  Deleting file "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
  Touching "x64\Release\ZERO_CHECK\ZERO_CHECK.tlog\ZERO_CHECK.lastbuildstate".
Done Building Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\ou
t\build\ZERO_CHECK.vcxproj" (default targets).
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
The target "BeforeGenerateProjectPriFile" listed in a BeforeTargets attribute at "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\NuGet\Microsoft.NuGet.targets (186,61)" does not exist in the p
roject, and will be ignored.
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\instal
l.vcxproj" (1) is building "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d450
51\out\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (3) on node 1 (default targets).
Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\ALL_BU
ILD.vcxproj" (3) is building "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d4
5051\out\build\onig.vcxproj" (4) on node 1 (default targets).
InitializeBuildStatus:
  Touching "onig.dir\Release\onig.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
CustomBuild:
  All outputs are up-to-date.
  Building Custom Rule C:/Users/user/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/onig_sys-61.1.0/oniguruma/CMakeLists.txt
  CMake does not need to re-run because D:/syntect/target/debug/build/onig_sys-d6
33e4c1e0d45051/out/build/CMakeFiles/generate.stamp is up-to-date.
ClCompile:
  F:\VisualStudio2015\VC\bin\x86_amd64\CL.exe /c /I"D:\syntect\target\debug\build
\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build" /I"C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma" /nologo /W1 /WX- /O2 /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
/D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Release\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /MD /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"onig.dir\Release\\" /Fd"onig.dir\Release\onig.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue "C:\
Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c"
  regenc.c
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): warning C4273: 'OnigEncDefaultCharEncoding': inconsistent dll linkage [D
:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(227): note: see previous definition of 'OnigEncDefaultCharEncoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): error C2099: initializer is not a constant [D:\User\\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(36): warning C4273: 'onigenc_init': inconsistent dll linkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(343): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_init'
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(345): note: see previous definition of 'onig_initialize_encoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(53): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_default_encoding': inconsistent dll linkage
[D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(349): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_default_encoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(59): warning C4273: 'onigenc_set_default_encoding': inconsistent dll linkage
[D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(347): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_set_default_encoding'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(66): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_head': inconsistent dll li
nkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcx
proj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(359): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_he
ad'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(77): warning C4273: 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_head_with_prev': inconsist
ent dll linkage [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\buil
d\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\oniguruma.h(353): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_get_right_adjust_char_he
ad_with_prev'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(861): warning C4273: 'onigenc_mb4_is_code_ctype': inconsistent dll linkage [D
:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(149): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_mb4_is_code_ctype'
C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(876): warning C4273: 'onigenc_with_ascii_strncmp': inconsistent dll linkage [
D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  c:\users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.h(220): note: see previous definition of 'onigenc_with_ascii_strncmp'
Done Building Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\ou
t\build\onig.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\ou
t\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\ou
t\build\install.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.

"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\install.vcxpro
j" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxp
roj" (default target) (3) ->
"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj"
(default target) (4) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): warning C4273: 'OnigEncDefaultCharEncoding': inconsistent dll linkage
[D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(861): warning C4273: 'onigenc_mb4_is_code_ctype': inconsistent dll linkage
[D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]
  C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(876): warning C4273: 'onigenc_with_ascii_strncmp': inconsistent dll linkage
 [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]



"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\install.vcxpro
j" (default target) (1) ->
"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\ALL_BUILD.vcxp
roj" (default target) (3) ->
"D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj"
(default target) (4) ->
(ClCompile target) ->
  C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\onig_sys-61.1.0\oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): error C2099: initializer is not a constant [D:\syntect\target\debug\build\onig_sys-d633e4c1e0d45051\out\build\onig.vcxproj]

    45 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:03.85

--- stderr
DIST_NAME: onig
DIST_VERSION: 6.1.1
DIST_LICENSE: BSD
DIST_AUTHOR: K.Kosako
DIST_MAINTAINER: K.Kosako
DIST_URL: https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma
DIST_DESC: Oniguruma is a regular expressions library.
DIST_DEPENDS:
thread 'main' panicked at '
command did not execute successfully, got: exit code: 1

build script failed, must exit now', C:\Users\User\.cargo\registry\src\github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823\cmake-0.1.21\src\lib.rs:605
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.


D:\syntect>
```

Comment: *oniguruma\src\regenc.c(32): error C2099: initializer is not a constant* — that's why. For whatever reason, that line of C code is not compatible with your C compiler.

Comment: I downloaded the `oniguruma` and run the `make_win32` and it compiled successfully, with the same compiler (VS 2015). But somehow, when `Rust` is doing it, it is not working.

Comment: @user: Might be a different set of flags. Tracking down the line of the error I get https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/master/src/regenc.c#L32, where [`ONIG_ENCODING_DEFAULT` aliases `ONIG_ENCODING_ASCII`](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/d5e9cc2de2431fbaa833a9202e3cc89661dd95fe/src/regenc.h#L116) which is defined as [the address of a global](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma/blob/dacfaba1082a00abea5d564931458f8d659bf3f2/src/oniguruma.h#L205). It's indeed not a constant in C (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050), so maybe you compiled in C++ mode?

Comment: Thanks. Thought I do not know how I compiled (I just called `make_win32.bat`), but I found on the issue https://github.com/trishume/syntect/issues/48, they said is it just because `onig_sys` doesn't build on Windows, which is reported on the issue https://github.com/rust-onig/rust-onig/issues/35, Therefore what you said seem to be the way to fix the `onig_sys` compiling on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oniguruma doesn't build with CMake on Windows MSVC. This [was an open issue](https://github.com/rust-onig/rust-onig/issues/35) in the `onig_sys` crate.

I've now [updated the way the `onig_sys` crate builds](https://github.com/rust-onig/rust-onig/pull/36) so it should work with MSVC now.

To update to this fixed version make sure the `Cargo.toml` dependency for `onig` is set to either `1.2` or `1.2.1`:

```
[dependencies]
onig = "1.2"
```