# How to call a batch builder script on a Rust cargo build script?

Tags: windows, batch-file, rust, rust-cargo, oniguruma

#### How to call a batch builder script on a Rust cargo build script?

The project [rust-onig](https://github.com/rust-onig/rust-onig) requires to compile the [oniguruma](https://github.com/kkos/oniguruma) C project. This is originated from the question [error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v61.1.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864924/error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command-for-onig-sys-v61-1-0) which attempts to build `oniguruma` on windows. Afterwards was noticed on windows within Visual Studio 2015, we need to call the `make_win32.bat`, instead of `cmake` to build the `oniguruma` C project.

However I have no idea how to do the `cargo` builder to call the `make_win32.bat` build script. Based on [build-script](http://doc.crates.io/build-script.html), I edited the default builder [build.rs](https://github.com/rust-onig/rust-onig/blob/master/onig_sys/build.rs) which is attempting to use `cmake` instead of `make_win32.bat`:

```
extern crate pkg_config;
extern crate cmake;

// use std::env;

// fn compile_with_cmake() {
//     use cmake::Config;

//     let static_link = env::var("CARGO_FEATURE_STATIC_ONIG").is_ok();

//     // Builds the project in the directory located in `oniguruma`, installing it
//     // into $OUT_DIR
//     let mut c = Config::new("oniguruma");

//     let dst = if static_link {
//                   c.define("BUILD_SHARED_LIBS", "OFF")
//               } else {
//                   c.define("CMAKE_MACOSX_RPATH", "NO")
//               }
//               .build();

//     let link_type = if static_link {
//         "static"
//     } else {
//         "dylib"
//     };

//     println!("cargo:rustc-link-search=native={}",
//              dst.join("build").display());
//     println!("cargo:rustc-link-lib={}=onig", link_type);
// }

pub fn main() {

    println!("Opening MAIN!!!!!!!!\n\n\n\n");
    use std::process::Command;

    let status = Command::new("D:\\User\\Downloads\\rust-onig\\onig_sys\\oniguruma\\make_win32.bat").status().unwrap_or_else(|e|
    {
        panic!("failed to execute process: {}", e)
    });

    println!("process exited with: {}", status);
    println!("process exited with: {}", status);
    println!("process exited with: {}", status);
    println!("process exited with: {}", status);
    println!("process exited with: {}", status);

    // if let Ok(_) = pkg_config::find_library("oniguruma") {
    //     return;
    // }

    // compile_with_cmake();
}
```

But my builder script is not called, as the message `process exited with` is never showed:

```
D:\Downloads\rust-onig>cargo build
   Compiling onig_sys v61.1.0 (file:///D:/User/Downloads/rust-onig/onig_sys)
   Compiling onig v1.2.0 (file:///D:/User/Downloads/rust-onig)
warning: unused import: `c_ulong`, #[warn(unused_imports)] on by default
 --> src\names.rs:6:27
  |
6 | use libc::{c_int, c_uint, c_ulong, c_void, c_uchar};
  |                           ^^^^^^^

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 11.31 secs

D:\Downloads\rust-onig>
```

What is displayed, when do we attempt to used the `cmake` builder can be viewed on the question This is originated from the question [error: failed to run custom build command for `onig_sys v61.1.0`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42864924/error-failed-to-run-custom-build-command-for-onig-sys-v61-1-0)

The problem there is `cmake` is generating several `Visual Studio` projects, which purely do not know how to build `oniguruma`. The only solution able to effectively build it is the `make_win32.bat` which already comes within `oniguruma`. Moreover, we need to use the `make_win32.bat` instead of let `cmake` generating `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Run `cargo build -v -v` to see `println` output from `build.rs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I called it within `-vv`, as commented by [user1034749](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1034749), it outputted correctly and ran the `make_win32.bat` file.

I just have to put inside the `make_win32.bat` the command `cd D:\rust-onig\src` because the batch file was being ran on some folder elsewhere.

```
D:\rust-onig>cargo build -vv
       Fresh libc v0.2.21
       Fresh pkg-config v0.3.9
       Fresh lazy_static v0.2.4
       Fresh bitflags v0.7.0
   Compiling onig_sys v61.3.0 (file:///D:/User/Downloads/rust-onig/onig_sys)
     Running `D:\rust-onig\target\debug\build\onig_sys-a911e1c40e7ed561\build-script-build`
Opening MAIN!!!!!!!!





D:\rust-onig\onig_sys>cd /d D:\rust-onig\onig_sys\oniguruma\src

D:\rust-onig\onig_sys\oniguruma\src>copy config.h.win32 config.h
        1 file(s) copied.

D:\rust-onig\onig_sys\oniguruma\src>nmake -f Makefile.windows

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.23506.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

process exited with: exit code: 0
process exited with: exit code: 0
process exited with: exit code: 0
process exited with: exit code: 0
process exited with: exit code: 0
     Running `rustc --crate-name onig_sys onig_sys\src\lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 --cfg "feature=\"static_onig\"" -C metadata=071c5dad786f940b -C extra-filename=-071c5dad786f940b --out-dir D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps -L dependency=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps --extern libc=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps\liblibc-5dc7b85e748840b4.rlib`
   Compiling onig v1.2.2 (file:///D:/User/Downloads/rust-onig)
     Running `rustc --crate-name onig src\lib.rs --crate-type lib --emit=dep-info,link -C debuginfo=2 -C metadata=9cad49cfdc2b5108 -C extra-filename=-9cad49cfdc2b5108 --out-dir D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps -L dependency=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps --extern libc=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps\liblibc-5dc7b85e748840b4.rlib --extern lazy_static=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps\liblazy_static-82c2efae9a7bf732.rlib --extern onig_sys=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps\libonig_sys-071c5dad786f940b.rlib --extern bitflags=D:\rust-onig\target\debug\deps\libbitflags-65ddff5d2b91509e.rlib`
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 8.92 secs
```

---

## Update

The [rust-onig](https://github.com/rust-onig/rust-onig) developer had added built-in supported to call `nmake` directly instead of using a `batch` file: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42875974/4934640