# why cannot static structure pointer be initialized to address of a variable

Tags: c, pointers, static

I am getting error when i am initializing the structure in below form

```
static struct A* a = &apple->queue[queue_number];
static struct B* b = &banana->queue_a[queue_number];
```

I am getting error

```
Error:  #28: expression must have a constant value
```

I want to keep pointer a and b as static so that it's scope remain in same file.
Please help here

Comment: Let me guess: The variables `a` and `b` are global variables? Those needs to be initialized to compile-time constants, you can not use run-time variables for that. Please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so we don't have to guess.

Comment: It must be a constant value. This means **compile time constant**. Without seeing more of your code, it's impossible to suggest what you could do instead.

Comment: Is `&apple->queue[queue_number]` known at compile time? Only then it can be used to initialise static and/or global variables.

Comment: @alk which, in C, would AFAIR require at least `queue_number` to be a `#define` -- a static `const` won't do here...

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Fair enough ... the term "*known at compile*" is ambiguous as well. :-/

Comment: @alk especially because C++ would allow a `const` with static linkage ;) For a good answer, you'd probably write a chapter of a book :(

Comment: This `int i = 0; int * pi = &i;` would do in global scope. The address of `i` is "*known at compile time*".

Answer (score 1):

Its because `a` is of `static` type and it should be initialize with `constants` or values of variable(in your case its `&apple->queue[queue_number]`) known at *compile time* not at run time. 
From the C standard

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static
>   or thread storage duration shall be constant expressions or string
>   literals.

*I want to keep pointer a and b as static ?* One way to do is initialize first `a` with `NULL` & test it.

```
static struct A *a = NULL;
if(a == NULL) { /* point to remember when a become NULL it initialize again a */
        a = &apple->queue[queue_number]; /*initialize expected value here */ 
}
```

May be you want to read this [Error "initializer element is not constant" when trying to initialize variable with const](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3025050/error-initializer-element-is-not-constant-when-trying-to-initialize-variable-w)

Comment: You might want to in more detail explain what "constant"  means in *this* context, as it unfortunately is used somewhat ambiguous by the C Standard.

Comment: Instead of a separate flag variable,initialilze the pointer to `NULL`, and test that.

Comment: yes @Barmar that's a good idea  instead of separate flag variable

Comment: Click my answer as accepted if it really help you @sobincoder